# How to convert an image to greyscale?

Tags: java, graphics

I want to simply convert an image to greyscale. But all I get is a completely `black` image. Why?

```
BufferedImage original = ImageIO.read(url);
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();  
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);  
g.dispose();
```

It has the correct width and height like the source image, but is completely black...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing empty image to itself.

Change

```
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
```

to

```
g.drawImage(original, 0, 0, null);
```